# Unit test, Boost serialization

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm trying to create unit test that includes boost serialization and de-serialization.

I'm running into some problems regarding the value of the version within this content:

```
class Object
{
public:
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_value1);

        if (version >= 2)
        {
          ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_value2);
        }
};
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Object, 2)
```

And the code within the Unit Test:

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>
    SUITE(ObjectTest)
    {
         TEST_FIXTURE(ObjectTestFixture, testSerialize)
         {
        std::stringstream serialisationStream;
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive outputArchive(serialisationStream);
        outputArchive << boost::serialization::make_nvp("Object",object);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive inputArchive(serialisationStream);
        Object deserialized;
        inputArchive >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("Object", deserialized);
```

When I step debug i noticed that the version number is always '0'. Within this content.

During normal execution (when the object is serialized to a file and then read) the version value is correct.

So when I check the value 'm_value2' in the unit test content, the value is never equal between the object and the de-serialzed object because the 'm_value2' section is always skipped.

I don't know when and how the version number is added to the stream, I'm using the same methods during my unit test as I am in normal execution.

```
Name : outputArchive2
    Details:{<boost::archive::xml_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>> = {<boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >> = {os = @0xbfffc988, flags_saver = {s_save_ = @0xbfffc9b4, a_save_ = 4098}, precision_saver = {s_save_ = @0xbfffc9b4, a_save_ = 6}, archive_locale = {px = 0x90331e0}, locale_saver = {<boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable> = {<No data fields>}, s_save_ = @0xbfffc98c, a_save_ = {static none = 0, static ctype = 1, static numeric = 2, static collate = 4, static time = 8, static monetary = 16, static messages = 32, static all = 63, _M_impl = 0xb70ed1b4, static _S_classic = <optimized out>, static _S_global = <optimized out>, static _S_categories = <optimized out>, static _S_once = <optimized out>}}}, <boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>> = {<boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>> = {<boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive> = {<No data fields>}, <boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, depth = 0, indent_next = true, pending_preamble = false}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}
    Default:{...}
    Decimal:{...}
    Hex:{...}
    Binary:{...}
    Octal:{...}
```

Comment: Looks like the object is stored with version 0, Can you post the content of serializationStream? It should be quite readable.

Comment: is `BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Object, 2)` macro visible in the same header file production and unit code uses?

Comment: there is the inlude of #include <boost/serialization/version.hpp> I would assume that it should be sufficient but it might not be.

Comment: From the code is not clear where stored 'objct' comes from.

Comment: @Samuel Hcorg didn't ask whether you included the macro definition. He asked whether your macro invocation has been seen. Exactly like he writes in his comment. My guess is: no